# How to set a timeout on an operation without creating a new thread Java

Tags: java

I have a for-loop that does some business logic for a variant number of times. I am looking for a way to set a timeout for each of the operations. I don't want to create a new thread to make use of executor service' Future timeout.

Comment: Check the expired time in each iteration.

Comment: any code examples for that?

Comment: What does this business logic consist of?

Comment: writing something to redis cache

Comment: Why don't you want a new Thread?

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this?

```
long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis(); //start time
for(Thing thing : listOfThings) {
    //how long we've been working
    if(System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime > someTimeThreshold) {
        break; //give up - taking too long
    }
    doSomething(thing);
}
```

Comment: That wont work.. if `doSomething(this)` takes longer than the timeout, it'll keep runningh until its done, since to get to the if statement, it first has to finish `doing something`.

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to have a timeout on an operation, in the same Thread.

This is because whatever it is you are doing, until its done, the code that's supposed to check for timeout wont run.

The only possible way you can do *something close to a timeout* is to put timeout checks **inside** your operations, as many times as possible (ideally, after every single operation that might take longer than a few ms).

But this wont work if you have even a single operation there, that takes a long time itself, because for example, if your timeout is set to 5 seconds, and this one operation takes 2.5 seconds, but you start executing it after 4.5 seconds, the timeout check will only be reached after `4.5 + 2.5 = 7 seconds`, meaning your code will run `2 seconds` or `40% longer` than your timeout is set to.

To be able to handle timeout correctly, efficiently, without copy-pasting the same check a thousand times, and reliably.. you absolutely **have** to use another thread.

Comment: Agreed, but it all depends on the unstated requirements for the timeout. If my real requirement is "completes in a reasonable time", then I might not really care that on occasion it'll take 7 seconds rather than 5 seconds.  Of course, I need to convince myself that a single execution of doSomething() has a reasonable bound on time.